# Facebook Graph API SSL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

I am trying to post to a facebook fan page wall using [fb_graph 1.3.9](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) gem in ruby. That is working fine on a ubuntu box but not on FreeBSD

I receive the error below:

> Got an error: SSL Verification failed
>   -- Preverify: false, Error: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)

Any idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: I'm getting the same error -- did you resolve it?

I posted to the google group for fb_graph.

Comment: not solved the problem but you can disable ssl verification.

Comment: How do you disable ssl verification?